# Can apt query a package repo for the creation date of a package's files?

Tags: debian, apt

How can apt query a package repo for the creation date of a package's files?

It is possible for apt to query a package repository for the creation dates for the files of a package , based on the package version as well?

Does it have the ability to do that whether or not the package is locally installed as well?

Comment: Why do you want to know the creation date?

Comment: To compare it with other repos that provide the same packages

Comment: Isn't a package usually built once and then mirrored to all repositories? There shouldn't be a difference.

Comment: By other repos I mean different package creators, not mirrors of the same repos. eg comparing something in a launchpad ppa with official debian packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can query the repositories directly, but you could download the packages and then use

```
dpkg --contents <package.deb>
```

Which should list all the files in the package, including permissions, ownership and **timestamps**.

If you want to compare different packages, it might also be useful to compare the changelogs. There is `apt-get changelog`, but I am not sure if it is supported by all repositories.

Comment: +1. Note that `dpkg`/`dpkg-deb` internally calls `tar -tv` (the first `tar` in `$PATH` generally GNU `tar`) to list the files. When that is GNU `tar`, that output is missing the seconds (with other `tar` implementations, the time format is pretty useless and can also be affected by locales). `dpkg` also unsets the `TAR_OPTIONS` variable before calling `tar` so you can't pass `--full-time` that way. To get the seconds, you'd need to invoke it in an environment where `tar` is a wrapper script that calls GNU tar with `--full-time`. You'll want to use TZ=UTC0 as well for reliability.